# Mark drawable folder to be used by multiple device types

Tags: android, android-resources

I'm currently tweaking my application to work with different devices. I ran into a problem with the old *Nexus 7* (~216 ppi pixel density).

The problem is that it looks for drawables in `tvdpi`, failing to find that it uses `hdpi` assets. The assets that I want it to use are the `xhdpi` or `xxhdpi` drawables.

Is there a way for me to tell Android to use a specific folder for `xhdpi` devices and `sw600dp` devices (that have a dp value lower than xhdpi)?
I would prefer to avoid having to copy paste drawables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is use 'references' to drawables in the dpi folders, so you don't have to copy assets around.

It can become quite tricky, but a quick explanation is:

Name your drwawables myDrawable-xhdpi or something like that, and put them in the xhdpi or no-dpi folder.

Then create the resource folders :

values-tvpdi
values-xhpi

Inside of those folders create drawable.xml file, with an item for each drawable you want the nexus 7 to use (you will also need to create a drawable.xml in the values folder).

The items will look like:

@drawable/myDrawable-xhdpi

All layout files can just reference @drawable/myDrawable.

What we are doing is setting it up so that we can have only one drawable, but referencing that drawable from these drawable.xml files. When Android is asked to look for myDrawable on a tvpdi device, it will look in the drawable-tvdpi folder, which doesn't have a myDrawable, so it will then look in the drawable.xml file, and find a reference to the correct drawable to use.

Hope that makes sense.

Check out this article for more: http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2011/07/new-tools-for-managing-screen-sizes.html

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. I have differently sized versions of all assets in hdpi, xhdpi and xxhdpi folders. If I don't have an image in tvdpi, will referencing it in values not simply tell the Nexus 7 to use the version that's in hdpi?

Comment: Well as you said the nexus 7 is tvdpi, so if there is a a drawables.xml in tvdpi, the nexus 7 will use that. And if that drawabes.xml points to a drawable in the xhdpi folder, thats what the nexus 7 will use. Otherwise it would use hdpi assets.

Comment: So if I have an image called icon_friends.png and I have differently sized versions of that in drawable-hdpi, -xhdpi & --xhdpi (all named icon_friends.png). What do I put into the drawables.xml that is currently in drawable-tvdpi to tell it to use icon_friends.png from the xhdpi folder?

Comment: You would want to name the actual png file something different in the xhdpi folder, like icon_friends_xhdpi.png. Then have a drawables.xml in the tvdpi and xhdpi folder that have an drawable item named icon_friends, but point to icon_friends_xhdpi.png